# ProgressTracker and contract errors not showing up in console

Tags: windows, corda

On Windows, when running the nodes and interacting with them I don't get any feedback from the console apart from "Unstarted" and "Done". When it doesn't work it just says "Unstarted". And if it works it says both.

Also when I when I initiate a transaction that doesn't fulfill the contract, the error message doesn't show up.

ProgressTracker doesn't show anything either. I checked the log file and here are some lines that might have something to do with the ProgessTracker:

```
[WARN ] 2018-01-08T20:39:43,952Z [Node thread] flow.[e43ed38a-c959-4a6e-a2d2-a428b15e0d19].maybeWireUpProgressTracking - ProgressTracker has not been started
[WARN ] 2018-01-08T20:39:46,915Z [Node thread] flow.[e43ed38a-c959-4a6e-a2d2-a428b15e0d19].uncaughtException - Caught exception from flow
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot rewind a progress tracker once it has ended
at net.corda.core.utilities.ProgressTracker.setCurrentStep(ProgressTracker.kt:104) ~[corda-core-2.0.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:120) ~[corda-node-2.0.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:41) ~[corda-node-2.0.0.jar:?]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.run1(Fiber.java:1092) [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.exec(Fiber.java:788) [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.doExec(RunnableFiberTask.java:100) [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.run(RunnableFiberTask.java:91) [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at net.corda.node.utilities.AffinityExecutor$ServiceAffinityExecutor$1$thread$1.run(AffinityExecutor.kt:69) [corda-node-2.0.0.jar:?]
```

This all works on Mac devices with the same code.

[Hello World Part 2 doesn't show error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXtRS.png)

[This is how the progress tracker works in linux, but in Windows it just says Unstarted and then Done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/un9W9.png)

Comment: A few questions: 1. How are you running the flows?; 2. Which CorDapp are you running?; 3. Could you post a screenshot of your console after running a flow?; 4. Check your logs to see if you can see anything interesting there (each node has a `logs` folder). Thanks!

Comment: Hey Joel,
I am running the flows in the terminal. I am using a modified version of part two of the hello world tutorial. Although I also don't get any other feedback in the terminal when I run the completed tutorial itself. In the logs I can't see anything except for what I posted above.

Comment: Are you sure you're using exactly the same code on both machines? As part of Hello, World, we don't define any progress tracker steps. Can you try running the flows from this CorDapp on Windows, since we know they work? https://github.com/corda/cordapp-example

Comment: Yes, exactly the same code. The first picture is when I run the flows in the completed Hello World tutorial, It's not showing the error when I enter a value that is not under 100. I modified it after to add progress tracking and a few other things. It's working how it should in the second picture, which is on linux. However on windows, with the exact same code, I only get "Unstarted" and "Done".

I ran the cordapp-example and it's working properly.

Comment: Hey.. did you fixed it? I am also getting the same error while running Hello World sample

Answer (score 0):

Given we don't have the code in front of us there's no way for us to know why the progress tracker is trying to rewind.

It's possible though that you are calling and setting the progress tracker states in the wrong order from their definition when you instantiate it in the flow class. I'd take a look at that if you're coming against this issue. I'm inclined to believe that's where the issue is.

That being said, this issue looks like it was from a while ago, and for you to only be having this issue when running on windows seems like it could have been a pretty obscure bug if this code ran on other platforms.

You may have some success trying your code on the latest version of corda? (they're now on 4.5 and shouldn't have any problems on windows.

here's a link to the docs page for downloading and running the latest corda jar files: https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.4/node-upgrade-notes.html#step-4-replace-cordajar-with-the-new-version

good luck!